# What is the geometric significance of the first $k$ derivatives of a curve $c: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ being linearly independent?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question

What is the geometric significance of the first $k$ derivatives of a smooth curve $c: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ being linearly independent? I understand that this is a necessary and sufficient condition to constructing a frenet frame for the curve, but I was hoping somebody could give me some additional insight. Thanks!

Comment: For starters, it tells you that the curve does not lie in a $(k-1)$-dimensional affine subspace.

Comment: That's certainly a great start! Great insight as always Ted!!!!!

Comment: P.S. Even locally.

Comment: Hm. Right. Fascinating stuff, thanks.

Comment: Ted's comment reminded me of this silly remark: if you have a parametrized curve in $\Bbb R^n$ whose entries are all polynomials of degree at most $k$, then the image of $c$ is contained in a (possibly affine) subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of dimension at most $k$. Proof: Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the first 2 are linearly dependent your curve is just a straight line. On the other hand if they are orthogonal than speed is constant which in the non-trivial case makes your curve a circle.  Dv*v=0
2Dv*v=0=D(v*v) which implies v*v =0.